# Подключение QChartView как кастомного виджета в Qt Designer

Tags: qt

Пытаюсь подключить `QChartView` как кастомный виджет, способом, описанным в документации.

Делаю "Преобразовать в...":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем преобразовываю в него QGraphicView. При компиляции возникает ошибка в автоматически генерируемом файле формы:

> C:\Users\Shmeisser\Documents\build-DBHandler-Desktop_Qt_5_7_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\ui_dbanalyzewindow.h:34: ошибка: 'QChartView' does not name a type
>        QChartView *graphicsView;

В .pro файл `QT += charts` подключено, проект пересобирал. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В "Преобразовать в..." нужно вписывать следующее:

> Base class name: QWidget
>
> Promoted class name: QtCharts::QChartView
>
> Header file: QtCharts/QChartView
>
> Global include: checked